# Como obtener la fecha con el evento click usando fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

estoy utilizando el la librería fullcalendar. 
El principal problema que me estoy encontrando es que necesito obtener la fecha que fue seleccionada en el calendario. Es decir, ¿Hay alguna manera de capturar la fecha cada vez que hago clic una fecha especifica en el calendario?

Si bien estoy obteniendo la fecha y guardándola en un campo de texto, no puede obtener el valor actualizado en el caso de que quiera seleccionar otro día.

Adjunto el código que estoy utilizando para obtener la fecha y almacenarlo en un campo de texto.

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'next'
  },
  editable: true,
  dayRender: function(date, cell) {
    $(cell).addClass('disabled');
  },
  dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
    $('#textFecha').val(date.format());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.2.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.2.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form-grup">
    <input type="text" id="textFecha" class="form-control input-sm" name="textFecha" value="" placeholder="Fecha" readonly>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id='calendar'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Agrego el segmento de código donde estaría tomando el valor del imput cada vez que sufre un cambio, pero no me estaria funcionnando.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#textFecha', function(event) {
 var fechaSeleccionada = $('#textFecha').val();
    fechaSeleccionada = formatoFecha(fechaSeleccionada);
    alert(fechaSeleccionada);
});
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Porque no (_en lugar de detectar el cambio_) hacer lo que necesitas en el método donde cambias el valor? es decir, hacer/llamar desde `dayClick`

Comment: como seria, no entendí?

Comment: Lo que quise decir es porque necesitas escuchar el evento de cambio si ya sabes cuando y desde donde lo cambias